# Editing a javascript document.write(variable)

Tags: javascript

I have a JS function

```
function setComparison(data) {
    var w= window.open('', 'comparison', 'width=600, height=400');
    w.document.open();
    w.document.write(getComparisonContent(data));
    w.document.close();
    return false;
}
```

I don't have access to the code that creates (data), but I need to replace a string in (data). Is there a way to pipe (data) through a string replace method?

Comment: `Regular Expressions` are your friend.

Comment: What exactly is in "data"?

Comment: if `data` is string you can use `data.replace()`.

Comment: What **can** you? Can you change the inside code of the `setComparison(data)` function?

Comment: use `innerHTML` instead of `doc.write`

Comment: @opus I think creating a new iframe content is a valid use case for this and not WTFy in this situation. While this is a good suggestion, I can't see how `innerHtml` would help here, except maybe to improve performance.

Comment: @JanDvorak:not thats not the solution just an advice..you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`data.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) seems to be your best bet...

```
function setComparison(data) {
    var w= window.open('', 'comparison', 'width=600, height=400');
    w.document.open();
    data = data.replace("foo", "bar");
    w.document.write(getComparisonContent(data));
    w.document.close();
    return false;
}
```

Here `foo` will be replaced with `bar`

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer didn't work for me but this did:

```
function setComparison(data) {
    var w= window.open('', 'comparison', 'width=600, height=400');
    w.document.open();
    html = html.replace("string to replace", "replacement text");
    w.document.write(getComparisonContent(data));
    w.document.close();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what's `html`? where was it in your question? this is ridiculous.